# Is it possible to have my dock visible on all monitors in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, dock

Don't mark this as a duplicate. Question has been asked several times in several places but it was years ago.

I have two monitors connected. One primary (that has dock at the bottom) and secondary. My monitors aren't mirrored (cloned). Both of them display different stuff but the dock appears just on the primary one.

**Is it possible to see my dock *(the same dock)* on both of them?**

Answer (score 6):

After extensive search, I have not found any solution specifically for the native macOS Dock.

However, not wanting to put up with this nuisance, I configured the third party [Contexts app](https://contexts.co/) to always be visible and show only icons when not hovered.

I'm more than happy with this solution. The only drawback is that you cannot configure the context sidebar to be in the bottom of the display, like the dock.

**Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with this app in any way.**

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue. I found [a somewhat useful article](http://osxdaily.com/2013/11/17/show-dock-external-display-mac-os-x/).

It's saying that you can view the dock on a secondary monitor if you swipe your mouse down twice (towards the edge of the screen) to view the dock on the secondary monitor. The issue is that it disappears from the other monitor. So, you will end up doing it as often as you switch from one monitor to another and need the dock.

I'm curious if there's a better solution to this.

Comment: I saw this article before. It's now what I'm looking for. No dragging, no clicking, no other actions. I just want the dock to be cloned out of the box. Without any additional actions. Anyway, thanks for your feedback (edit: I didn't down vote your answer).

Comment: Thanks, swiping down twice towards bottom edge works perfectly and absolutely suits me.
But.... how to hide it back? How to revert this action? Sometimes I need it too :D

Comment: How would/could this work when your dock is not located at the bottom of your screen and when your screens are in the direction of the dock ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Mission Control preferences (click Apple icon in upper left of screen, then "System Preferences" then "Mission Control). Then check "Displays have separate spaces." See image below.

Note: if you use multiple Spaces, checking this box will change how they behave. Switching Spaces will now only switch Spaces on the monitor that is currently active, rather than switching Spaces simultaneously across all monitors (the behavior when that box is not checked).

[image]

Comment: That absolutely doesn't work and makes no effect on the dock.

Comment: Did you log out and back in after making that change? This is necessary. When you made the change, did you then see a menubar at the top of each monitor (this would be a sign that the change took effect).  Are your two monitors arranged (in Display Preferences) so that one is stacked on top of the other? That might be causing the dock to only appear on the 'bottom' monitor.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, on Sierra

Comment: This also has the negative side effect that applications can't span multiple monitors

Comment: Per the article posted by c1p0, this option is apparently required in order to allow the dock to be on monitors other than the primary.  However it does not seem to allow the dock to be on multiple monitors simultaneously as this question asks for.